# Need help in Python OOP implementing class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm need everyone here advise to guide me, I'm trying to a class in Python OOP, this is my below code. I already import abstractmethod but not sure why there's error below. I don't understand how to resolve this.. Can anyone help me out?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Employee(ABC):
    def __init__(self, employeeId, name, workFromHome, leaveBalance = 0):
        self._employeeId = employeeId
        self._name = name
        self._workFromHome = workFromHome
        self._leaveBalance = leaveBalance

    @property
    def employeeId(self):
        return self._employeeId
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    
    @property
    def workFromHome(self):
        return self._workFromHome
    @workFromHome.setter
    def workFromHome(self, atHome):
        self._workFromHome = atHome
        
    @abstractmethod
    def getLeaveEntitlement(self):
        pass
    
    #Other Methods
    def adjustLeave(self, adjustment):
        self._leaveBalance += adjustment
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID {self._employeeId} Name: {self._name} Leave Balance: {self._leaveBalance} WFH: {self._workFromHome}'
    
def main():
    
    e1 = Employee('101', 'Jeff', 20, 'Yes')
    print(e1)

    
main()
```

### Error Encounted:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
40
41
---> 42 main()

in main()
36 def main():
37
---> 38     e1 = Employee('101', 'Jeff', 20, 'Yes')
39     print(e1)
40

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Employee with abstract methods getLeaveEntitlement

If Working This is the Result:
**ID: 101 Name: Jeff Leave Balance: 20 WFH: No**

Answer (score 0):

Since Employee is an ABC, you cannot directly instantiate it. Only classes that 1) inherit from it, and 2) implement its abstract methods are allowed to be instantiated. There's nothing "wrong" with your code, this is a design constrain.

The following code adds the `EmployeeChildClass` that inherits from `Employee` and works as you'd expect:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Employee(ABC):
    def __init__(self, employeeId, name, workFromHome, leaveBalance = 0):
        self._employeeId = employeeId
        self._name = name
        self._workFromHome = workFromHome
        self._leaveBalance = leaveBalance

    @property
    def employeeId(self):
        return self._employeeId
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    
    @property
    def workFromHome(self):
        return self._workFromHome
    @workFromHome.setter
    def workFromHome(self, atHome):
        self._workFromHome = atHome
        
    @abstractmethod
    def getLeaveEntitlement(self):
        pass
    
    #Other Methods
    def adjustLeave(self, adjustment):
        self._leaveBalance += adjustment
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ID {self._employeeId} Name: {self._name} Leave Balance: {self._leaveBalance} WFH: {self._workFromHome}'


# Dummy implementation
class EmployeeChildClass(Employee):
    def getLeaveEntitlement(self):
        return None


def main():
    
    e1 = EmployeeChildClass('101', 'Jeff', 20, 'Yes')
    print(e1)

    
main()
```